# SELECTing newest entries for each item in a large dataset

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

So, i have a table with roughly 1.5 million rows in it, looking somewhat like this:

```
name   | time       | data1 | data2  
--------------------------------------
 93-15 | 1337348782 |   11  | 60.791 
 92-02 | 1337348783 |   11  | 62.584 
 92-02 | 1337348056 |   11  | 63.281
 93-15 | 1337348068 |    8  | 65.849
 92-02 | 1337348117 |   11  | 63.271 
 93-15 | 1337348129 |    8  | 65.849 
 92-02 | 1337348176 |   10  | 63.258 
 93-15 | 1337348188 |    8  | 65.849 
 92-02 | 1337348238 |   10  | 63.245 
 93-15 | 1337348248 |    8  | 65.849
```

...these correspond to historical status updates from something that needs to be monitored. Now, what i would like to do is to find the current status if each unit.

It wasn't hard finding similar questions here on stackoverflow, and extrapolating from the findingsat, i came up with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles v
  JOIN ( SELECT  MAX(time) as max, name
    FROM vehicles
    GROUP BY name)
  m_v
ON (v.time = m_v.max AND v.name = m_v.name);
```

but seeing as i have roughly 1.5 million rows (and counting), is there a different approach that allows for a faster query?

Comment: Please, post here also the `EXPLAIN` output for your query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WITH
  sequenced_data
AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time DESC) AS sequence_id,
    *
  FROM
    vehicles
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced_data
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

A covering index on `(name, time)` would be helpful too.

**EDIT:** Notes on how it work, etc.

PostgreSQL has what are know as windowing or analytical functions.  These generally take the form `some_function() OVER (PARTITION BY some_fields ORDER BY some_fields)`.

In this case I used `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time DESC)`.

`ROW_NUMBER()` creates a unique row number for a set of data.  `1 to n` for `n` records.

`PARTITION BY name` means that this function is applied independently to different names.  Each `name` is it's own group/window/partition, and the results of `ROW_NUMBER()` start over from `1` again for each group/window/partition.

`ORDER BY time DESC` takes all the records in one group/window/partition and orders them by the `time` field, with the highest value first, before the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is applied.

For your example data, therefore, you get this...

```
 name  | time       | data1 | data2  | row_number
--------------------------------------------------

 92-02 | 1337348783 |   11  | 62.584 | 1
 92-02 | 1337348238 |   10  | 63.245 | 2
 92-02 | 1337348176 |   10  | 63.258 | 3
 92-02 | 1337348117 |   11  | 63.271 | 4
 92-02 | 1337348056 |   11  | 63.281 | 5

 93-15 | 1337348782 |   11  | 60.791 | 1
 93-15 | 1337348248 |    8  | 65.849 | 2
 93-15 | 1337348188 |    8  | 65.849 | 3
 93-15 | 1337348129 |    8  | 65.849 | 4
 93-15 | 1337348068 |    8  | 65.849 | 5
```

Because the ordering is `time DESC`, the highest valued `time` field, in each `name` group/window/partition, will always have a `row_number` of `1`.

Having an index on `(name, time)` makes it much easier for the optimiser by ensuring the data is in a friendly order.  This means that `ROW_NUMBER()` isn't actually applied to all the records; as soon as it finds the highest valued `time` record, and assigns `ROW_NUMBER() = 1`, it knows it can stop and move on to the next `name`.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further, and elaboratE?

Comment: @Jarmund - Yup, added as much as I can think of without getting bored :)